# Why wont my if statements work?

Tags: c++, if-statement

Hi my if statements wont work here is my code please help?

```c++
case WM_COMMAND:
  {

    if (LOWORD(wParam) == 3); {

      std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    break;

    if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1); {

      system("test.txt");

    }


    break;
  }
```

i just don't get it!

Comment: `if (LOWORD(wParam) == 3); { if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1); {` remove the semi-colon.

Comment: With /W3 or higher: *warning C4390: ';': empty controlled statement found; is this the intent?*

Answer (score 2):

Control structers govern either the next bracket, or everything to the next semikolon. What you wrote is interpreted as:

```
//This is a really short if, but okay
if (LOWORD(wParam) == 3); 

//this is just a bracket that has nothing to do with the if that was already finished.
{

      std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh i fixed it here is my code:

```
        case WM_COMMAND: {

    if (LOWORD(wParam) == 3) {
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) {
    system ("test.txt");
    }


    break;
    }
```